# Can not sync my django database after installing django.contrib.comments app

Tags: django, django-models, django-fluent

Error that I have:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
comments.comment: Accessor for field 'content_type' clashes with related field 'ContentType.content_type_set_for_comment'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'content_type'.
comments.comment: Reverse query name for field 'content_type' clashes with related field 'ContentType.content_type_set_for_comment'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'content_type'.
comments.comment: Accessor for field 'site' clashes with related field 'Site.comment_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'site'.
comments.comment: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.comment_comments'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
comments.comment: Reverse query name for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.comment_comments'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
comments.commentflag: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.comment_flags'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
comments.commentflag: Reverse query name for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.comment_flags'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
```

In the beginning I installed newer app called **django_comments**, and did sync my database. But
after I decided to use **django-fluent-comments** that need django.contrib.comments. So insteed of django_comments I put django.contrib.comments.

After I sync database my django project crashed with the error above.

So, please help to solve this problem or give me some recommendations.

Thanks for any advices!

**PS:** I tried to create new project with another virtualenvironment and changed mysql to sqlite3, but still have this error.

Comment: What version of Django do you use ? Did you custom your site or user model ? According to the error, it has nothing to do with your database, but only with Django models not validating (everytime you run a runserver/syncdb, ... command it validates the models)

Comment: Sorry, but I found my mistake)) As you say it was in my models.py. There was some import from old app django_comments, so after I deleted this line everything start to work. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was because I forgot to delete all imports in my models from old app **django_comments**. So now everything works fine!

Comment: Strange error messages for such an error. Well I guess this could be usefull to other Django users later, even if django.contrib.comments is now deprecated :)